# Bios problems when attempting to install Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, hp, bios, usb-installation, process-priority

The bios on my HP pro 3120 MT does not contain a usb option. How do I install ubuntu? (PC needs to be formatted. Not planning to keep windows 7)

Comment: Boot from a DVD.

Comment: Sometimes the option is called "boot from disk" and after that you can choose a USB disk.

Comment: @Pilot6 There may not be an option for this model. Although, it may show up as a floppy? This model appears to only have a CD-ROM and might not have the option to boot from USB and may not have a DVD drive either (I had an old sony VIAO like this). https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02199913

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a CD-rom and you don't have a DVD drive, you can install Ubuntu from a "minimal CD" which is a text based installation program instead of a "live session" DVD or USB.

The CD will allow you to install Ubuntu but you won't be able to "take a test drive" like you would be able to do using a USB device.

---

**FIRST:**

[Click here to download the 64bit iso file.](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

or

[Click here to download the 32bit iso file instead.](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

---

**NEXT:**

[Click here and follow the instructions for how to burn an iso file to a disk using Windows.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

---

**THEN:**

Try pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> to access the boot menu when you turn the computer on.

There should be an option to boot from a CD-ROM on this screen.

Alternatively, you can set the CD-ROM as the 1st boot device in your BIOS settings.

[Click here for more instructions on how to set this setting in your BIOS.](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02199913)

---

**FINALLY:**

Boot the computer using the CD-ROM to boot the computer. Also, "Gnome Shell" is the default Ubuntu desktop environment but you can a different [Ubuntu flavour](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours) if you want to.

> To install, boot your computer from the the mini iso and select
>   "Install" at the prompt. You can then follow the instructions from the
>   text-based installer. On the software selection screen, you can select
>   from a number of collections of software such as different desktop
>   environments (kde, xfce, etc), a multitude of different servers,
>   multimedia creation tools, media center (mythbuntu), etc. You can also
>   select "Manual package selection" which will take you to aptitude. You
>   may also select nothing and just continue to finish the installation.
>   If you selected nothing, upon reboot you will arrive at a cli prompt;
>   from here you can fully customize your new system.

Also, use your arrow keys and the <kbd>TAB</kbd> to navigate through the text based installation and use the  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and/or the  <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> to select the highlighted option when you need to (similar to how you would do stuff in the BIOS settings).

[Click here for more instructions on how to install using a "minimal CD"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

Comment: The options I have in bios are: Floppy group, Network Boot Group,  CD-Rom Group, Hard Drive Group. So if I move CD ROM group to : 1st and get Ubuntu on CD and install using the CD reader in the desktop. Then it should work?

Comment: @kimbetbaby Yes, I have updated the instructions. The CD image is a bit different from the USB installation method. The CD method has more of an "old school" feel to it and is an installation media only. There is no option to try Ubuntu without installing like there is with the USB method.

Comment: @kimbetbaby Are you sure USB drive is not in your "Hard Drive Group"?